# Added i386 support for wine, removed it now I can't remove the architecture

Tags: debian, dpkg, wine, x86, cpu-architecture

I've previously added i386 support in order to install `wine32` with:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Now I don't need `wine32` anymore and removed it, then wanted to remove the i386 architecture again, but it states:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
dpkg: error: cannot remove architecture 'i386' currently in use by the database
```

I assume that I could remove all i386 packages shown by `dpkg --list | grep i386`, but I'm not sure whether this may impair my systems functionality or not.

My question is, if its safe to remove the listed i386 packages, considering that I removed wine32.
Or on the other hand if it may interfere with my system in any way, if I keep the i386 architecture.

Debian Stretch 4.1.0-2-amd64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a debian amd64 system, the i386 architecture is an optional extra.  No i386 packages are required for the system to function.

If you are not using any 32-bit programs, you can safely remove all :i386 packages, and the i386 architecture.

Personally, I wouldn't bother removing them unless disk space was extremely tight.  The i386 packages do no harm and you may want to run 32-bit software again in the future.

Comment: thank you for the advice. Will aptitude install i386 if I don't explicitly tell it to? For instance when I `sudo apt-get install something` and something offers i386 packages?

Comment: Generally not.  The exception is when you install a 32-bit package that depends on 32-bit libraries - they will get installed too.  It won't install i386 packages at all if you've removed the arch with `dpkg --remove-architecture i386`

Comment: I would just add one thing - I was having similar problem for a long time and I unknowingly installed a lot of quite essencial packages as i386, so I didn't have them in amd64 form - this led to a lot of problems, because attempt at removing all i386 packages led to removing almost everything - after much despair and some googling, I resolved it by installing every package which didn't have it's amd64 counterpart and only then removing i386 packages and architecture - which now proceeded without any problems at all.